# filter and count with grep in a single pass?

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I am using `grep` at the end of a set of piped commands to filter some rows out of a file. Afterwards I will want to do some arithmetic based on the number of remaining rows.

e.g.

```
chrN="chr1|chr2|chr3|chr4|chr5|chr6|chr7"
otherCommands | grep -Ew $chrN  > $ChIP".bed"
count_pos=`wc -l $ChIP"bed" | awk '{print 1000000/$1}'`
```

It strikes me as very wasteful after piping together lots of command to then write it to a file and then read through it again just to collect one number. .. but I don't know how to do that.

So my question is how do I save the number of rows that passed the grep filter to the variable `count_pos` and save the filtered rows to the file too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `tee` to write to both a file and `stdout`:

```
chrN="chr1|chr2|chr3|chr4|chr5|chr6|chr7"
count_pos=$(otherCommands |
  grep -Ew "$chrN" |
  tee "$ChIP.bed" |
  wc -l |
  awk '{print 1000000/$1}')
```

Comment: OK, thats a great answer.. if I could just push it a little further?.. say I wanted not to write to the file but instead save the count in `count_pos` then use that as a variable in the next command of my now very long pipe?

Comment: @Stephen, Not sure what you mean. This will save the count in `count_pos` (`$()` is usually a better option than backticks).

Comment: No forget what I said.. I have to pass through all the data to count it .. Doh! So I might as well stop the pipe there. Apols and thx again..

Answer (score 6):

Do everything with awk. Initialize counter, count and print (grep+count) with pattern matching and output count at the end:

```
awk 'BEGIN { c=0} pattern{ c++; print $0 } END{ print 1000000/c }'
```

You don't have to print if you don't want to. Or, you could use `print $0 > output_file` inside awk to print grepped results in a file, and count on stdout.

Comment: thx, that is a good option but I think the above is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This replaces grep, tee, wc and awk in a single command.

Comment: indeed you maybe right, it maybe better, except for my innate fear of awk ;) I will test it though!

Comment: Then why use `awk` to do arithmetics? :)

I used to fear awk too. But it's just a very logical and powerful tool - it's like perl, except it's easier to read and works better in a pipe.